# How to get rid of Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack

Why I will get this error? How to get rid of it?

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

My code as below

```
    return Stack(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(color: const Color(0xff9Fc131)),
          ),
          Column(children: [
            Container(
                color: const Color(0xff9Fc131),
                child:
                    Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                  Text("This is top"),
                ])),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 20),
                            const Text(
                              "Invoice Items",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 15),
                            _showInvoiceItems()
                          ],
                        ))))
          ])
        ]);
      }

 Widget _showInvoiceItems() {
    return ListView.separated(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: invoice.invoiceItemList!.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final invoiceItem = invoice.invoiceItemList![index];
        return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Text(invoiceItem.item ?? ""),
        ]);
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return const Divider(
          color: Colors.grey,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**Output**
[image]

Thanks a lot!

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  <------- // please ignore this line as I just want to get rid of this error "*It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positional widgets like `Positioned`,`Align`.. on Stack instead of `Expanded`. You can go through this snippet.

```dart
class F33 extends StatelessWidget {
  const F33({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: const Color(0xff9Fc131), //you may use scaffold background color
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: const Color(0xff9Fc131),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("This is top"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        const Text(
                          "Invoice Items",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15),
                        // _showInvoiceItems()
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! If I have more items in the listview, I will get `A RenderFlex overflowed by 93 pixels on the bottom` error..would you mind telling me how to fix?

Comment: try to change the scrollable physics , or just remove `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Comment: I  have removed `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, still getting the same issue.

Comment: I managed to fix..thanks